# How to debug a class library project?

Tags: c#, user-controls

Well, there may be a obvious answer to this question and I may be missing a very basic point here.

I have downloaded a simple application from codeproject.com which creates a toolbar in IE. The application output is set as 'Çlass Library'. Now I understand that I cannot run this application from its current settings.

I made some changes in the downloaded source code (say add a new button on toolbar). I want to debug this project and see how does changes look like before I finally deploy it/ install it In IE. But I don't know how to debug a project which is purely a user control and cannot run its own.

Could someone please help me what I am missing here? Is there any simple way where I can debug this project right from visual studio like I do with simple windows forms application or web applications or a console application.

Comment: create another web application project in the solution, call it MyWebAppProj. Then in MyWebAppProj add a reference to your class library. Then add the user control to the default.aspx insite MyWebAppProj. Then run MyWebAppProj.

Comment: @br1 i tried using the way you suggested. But I'm unable to get it? Is there any other solution??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your control lives in another process, you have to get your debugger attached to that process.  Either manually attach to it (if it's already running), or change your debugger settings to launch the host process.